# Gutenberg RichText

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I'm using the RichText API for a custom block:

```
<RichText
  tagName="a"
  className="button"
  placeholder={ __( 'Button text...' ) }
  value={ buttonText }
  onChange={ ( value ) => setAttributes( { buttonText: value } ) }
 />
```

I am using `a` as the tag name because I want the element to be a link but I'm not sure how to add a URL. Is it possible to add a `href` attribute? Adding `href="some URL"` to RichText does not work. I looked through the documentation and Googled it but couln't find any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please paste the full code, According to official Gutenberg button block. You need to have additional block attributes to use for button link,text -

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-library/src/button/index.js

```
<RichText.Content
    tagName="a"
    className={ linkClass }
    href={ url }
    title={ title }
    style={ buttonStyle }
    value={ text }
/>
```

As you can see, there's a **URL, Title & Text** attributes.

```
url: {
        type: 'string',
        source: 'attribute',
        selector: 'a',
        attribute: 'href',
    },
    title: {
        type: 'string',
        source: 'attribute',
        selector: 'a',
        attribute: 'title',
    },
    text: {
        type: 'array',
        source: 'children',
        selector: 'a',
    },
```